# Bootstrap: set navbar-fixed-top background semi-transparent only when opened

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building an Angularjs + Twitter Bootstrap application.
I would like to use a *navbar-fixed-top* class for my top navbar, because I want - in mobile (collapsed) mode - the drop-down of navbar items to be shown *over* the page contents, without pushing down contents.
I would also like to have the background of the *opened* drop-down to be semi-transparent.  I think I am quite there with a css like this:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  background-image: none;
}
```

The only problem is that with this css the *closed* navbar is semi-transparent, too.
Is it possible to set css attributes *only* to *opened* navbar?

**UPDATE:**
From *srrvnn* answer (thanks!), I did solve with:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapsing,
.navbar-collapse.in {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
}
```

Comment: @Adrift: I mean the collapsed dropdown...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The navbar goes through two classes and we need to  modify both.

```
.navbar-collapse.collapsing,   
.navbar-collapse.in {

    position: absolute; 
    background-color: // whatever for transparent

}
```

By making `position: absolute`, we remove it out of flow thus making it appear over our content, and we also set our background property here.

Comment: I think it's *quite* right... Though, here the background is a ligher gray, but not transparent... Do I miss something like `.navbar-inner`, perhaps?

Comment: Did you try setting the color to white, and setting an opacity value? Or maybe, the actual content below your navbar is gray.

Comment: Sorry, it works perfectly... I did remove "position:absolute" from my class becasue I tought that *navbar-fixed-top* would have already removed it out of flow... but, without "position:absolute", also transparency is lost... :-)